# -- lateral injecting a strange outer join condition

Tags: postgresql

[**dbfiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=180771988428980b583ad817f21d4df5)
code source: https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/test/regress/sql/join.sql;h=7f866c603b8d65524584f16ae96205e1dad32e0b;hb=9eacee2e62d89cab7b004f97c206c4fba4f1d745#l1819

Trying to understand following query: X.

```
select * from int8_tbl a,
    int8_tbl x left join lateral
    (select a.q1 from int4_tbl y)
    ss(z) 
    on x.q2 = ss.z
    order by a.q1, a.q2, x.q1,x.q2,ss.z;
```

Then I thought I first need to understand the following query: Y.

```
select * from
    int8_tbl x left join lateral
    (select x.q1 from int4_tbl y)
    ss(z) 
    on x.q2 = ss.z;
```

To understand Y then I try to rewrite the query, then try to match the result.(I know this methodology is not right)
The following is so far what I tried.

```
--no lateral will not work.
select * from
    int8_tbl x left join
    (select x.q1 from int4_tbl y)
    ss(z) 
    on x.q2 = ss.z;
    
-- the following is not the same as --the QUERY Y
select * from
    int8_tbl x left join
    (select y.q1 from int8_tbl y) ss(z) 
on x.q2 = ss.z;

-- the following is not the same as --the QUERY Y
select * from int8_tbl x, int8_tbl y
where x.q2 = y.q1;

-- the following is not the same as --the QUERY Y
select * from int8_tbl x  join int8_tbl y
on x.q2 = y.q1;
```

So How to explain the query Y.

Comment: It is a regression test.  It is not supposed to make sense, it is supposed to do weird things to make sure they don't blow up.

Comment: Does it help that the "," join in:  int8_tbl a, int8_tbl x can be rewritten as:  int8_tbl a CROSS JOIN int8_tbl x ?